# Spark Last task takes time to complete

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, skew

I am having two parquet files 1st one is of 10 GB and 2nd is of 800 MB.

I was executing below query in azure databricks on spark cluster and storing result into DBFS.

```
val interim_nobed_main=spark.read.format("delta").option("header","true").load(s"${Interimpath}/cdf_hsc_interim_nobed").repartition(8)
interim_nobed_main.createOrReplaceTempView("hsc_interim_nobed")


Data repartition

+--------------------+--------+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|   count|
+--------------------+--------+
|                   1|56426303|
|                   6|56426352|
|                   3|56426283|
|                   5|56426248|
|                   4|56426265|
|                   7|56426335|
|                   2|56426293|
|                   0|56426317|
+--------------------+--------+
```

```
val facl_decn_bed_interim_main=spark.read.format("delta").option("header","true").load(s"${Interimpath}/cdf_hsc_facl_decn_bed_interim").repartition(8)
facl_decn_bed_interim_main.createOrReplaceTempView("h_facl_decn_bed_interim")

Data repartition
+--------------------+--------+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|   count|
+--------------------+--------+
|                   1|14345224|
|                   6|14345233|
|                   3|14345223|
|                   5|14345221|
|                   4|14345222|
|                   7|14345229|
|                   2|14345224|
|                   0|14345226|
+--------------------+--------+
```

Data is almost equally partioned.

```
spark.sql("""
select
nb.*,
facl.h_id as facl_decn_bed_h_id,
facl.bed_day_decn_seq_nbr as facl_decn_bed_seq_nbr,
case when facl.h_id is not null then concat(substr(nb.cse_open_dttm, 1, 10), ' 00:00:00.000') else cast(null as string) end as engage_dt
from hsc_interim_nobed nb
left outer join h_facl_decn_bed_interim facl on
(nb.h_id=facl.h_id and nb.facl_decn_h_id=facl.h_id)
where nb.facl_decn_h_id is not null
union all
select
nb.*,
cast(null as int) as facl_decn_bed_h_id,
cast(null as int) as facl_decn_bed_seq_nbr,
cast(null as string) as engage_dt
from hsc_interim_nobed nb
where nb.facl_decn_h_id is null""").write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("header","true").save(s"${Interimpath}/cdf_hsc_set1_interimdemo")
```

what could be the reason for this. And do I solve this?

Comment: Happens quite often that one task is stuck. You can use speculative execution - that is more workers then partitions. You  need to turn it on when you launch your spark-shell or submit

Comment: I was doing this on azure databricks.

Comment: I guess they too have speculative execution

Comment: Another idea - perhaps your partitions are equal at  the start, but after left outer join they get skewed

Comment: How can I know on what basis partition is happening.

Comment: Your write after left outer join one of my table has 200 partitions in which count for each partition is different and other has 10 partitions with equal no. of records in each partition. But I don't know on what basis this partitions are created. Please suggest.

Comment: I guess it depends on the number of matches you have in the join

Comment: That means is it based on h_id / facl_decn_h_id from my code above?